# cannot build and submit using gcloud

Tags: gcloud

I am becoming increasingly frustrated with the quickstart guide to deploying gcloud using Docker :

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build

I am following every step but cannot build using the command :

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/strange-vortex-286312/quickstart-image
```

If I list my projects this is what I see :

[image]

The tutorial says that I then use the PROJECT_ID and put it in the command which I listed above :

[image]

OK, fine. So I do exactly as the tutorial says, and run this command >

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/strange-vortex-286312/quickstart-image
```

but then I get this error :

```
FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://strange-vortex-286312_cloudbuild/source/1597335850.83144-c6bf33c39ca54474a15cf04835a07444.tgz#1597335851899497
Copying gs://strange-vortex-286312_cloudbuild/source/1597335850.83144-c6bf33c39ca54474a15cf04835a07444.tgz#1597335851899497...
/ [1 files][  263.0 B/  263.0 B]
Operation completed over 1 objects/263.0 B.
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker

                   ***** NOTICE *****

Alternative official `docker` images, including multiple versions across
multiple platforms, are maintained by the Docker Team. For details, please
visit https://hub.docker.com/_/docker.

                ***** END OF NOTICE *****

unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 9c7c268f-07f3-486e-842f-8c1a0e2877ae completed with status "FAILURE"
```

I am unsure what this error message is trying to tell me.

If I to my console then I see this error :

[image]

I am also unsure what this error is trying to tell me.

Comment: The error suggests that there is no `Dockerfile` in the directory from which you're running the `gcloud builds submit ...` command.

Comment: If that's not the issue, can you try `gcloud builds submit . --tag gcr.io/strange-vortex-286312/quickstart-image` **NOTE** the period between `submit` and `--tag`.

Comment: 3 important things:  please make sure the [CloudBuild API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=cloudbuild.googleapis.com&redirect=https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build&_ga=2.124718351.408069896.1597184789-2012370677.1584563265&_gac=1.184167954.1594071025.EAIaIQobChMIjbqJocm56gIVCtvACh3u6wPlEAAYASAAEgJyNvD_BwE) is enabled, which version of the SDK are you using, and have you tried using CloudShell?

Comment: Hi Daz, yes. I have DockerFile. I tried with the period "." and I still get the same error

Comment: Jose: (1) Enabled CloudBuildAPI still same error, (2) SDK of what? (3)  No havent tried CloudShell

Comment: Also the error seems to say it cant find DockerFile in "/workspace/Dockerfile". But I am running the command from "/quickstart-docker/" directory.

Comment: Also tried running through the CloudShell. Same problem. Google Cloud SDK is 305.0.0

Comment: OK. Figured out the problem. My docker file was called "DockerFile" instead of "Dockerfile". Very very misleading because "DockerFile" works in normal Docker, thats why I didnt think that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

OK. In my case the Dockerfile was incorrectly named.

I had..

> DockerFile

..and not

> Dockerfile

The capital F was the problem. It took me for ever to figure this out because DockerFile works in normal Docker so I didnt think there was an issue with capitalization.